# Pause button add new nodes on change

Tags: ios, objective-c, sprite-kit

i've implementing a pause and play button in my sprite kit game. The problem is it seems to add a new node each time the button is pressed. This would be quite ineffective. What i want is to replace the existing. How can i achieve this?

```
-(void)didMoveToView:(SKView *)view
{

    pauseButton = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 40, 40)];
    [pauseButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"pause"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [pauseButton addTarget:self action:@selector(pausedMenu:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

    [self.view addSubview:pauseButton];

}




-(void)pausedMenu:(SKView *)view
{

    menuBackground = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithColor:[SKColor colorWithWhite:0.0 alpha:0.2] size:CGSizeMake(self.frame.size.width*2, self.frame.size.height*2)];

    [self addChild:menuBackground];


    [pauseButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"start"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [pauseButton addTarget:self action:@selector(startMenu:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

    self.scene.paused = YES;

}

-(void)startMenu:(SKView *)view
{

    [menuBackground removeAllChildren];
    [pauseButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"pause"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [pauseButton addTarget:self action:@selector(pausedMenu:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    self.scene.paused = NO;

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you mean

```
[menuBackground removeFromParent];//add this
menuBackground = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithColor:[SKColor colorWithWhite:0.0 alpha:0.2] size:CGSizeMake(self.frame.size.width*2, self.frame.size.height*2)];
[self addChild:menuBackground];
```

And

```
[pauseButton removeFromParent];//add this
pauseButton = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 40, 40)];
    [pauseButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"pause"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [pauseButton addTarget:self action:@selector(pausedMenu:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
[self.view addSubview:pauseButton];
```